# svnadmin load error: svnadmin: E160006: No such revision

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndumpfilter

I am new to SVN and am performing a SVN repository to repository migration.

I need to exclude a folder from source repository dump file.
For that I used the following svndumpfilter command.

```
svndumpfilter exclude foldername --skip-missing-merge-sources --drop-empty-revs < full_dump_file > filtered_dump_file
```

Then i tried to load the filtered dumpfile in target repository with svnadmin load command.

```
svnadmin load target_repository < filtered_dump_file
```

But the loading of dump file stopped with error:

```
adding path : xxx/xxxxx/xxxx/pre ...svnadmin: E160006: No such revision 210
```

When I checked the revision 210 in source repository, a file is added on this revision (r210).

Answer (score 3):

Simply do not use the switch `--drop-empty-revs`. The empty revisions are needed by `svnadmin load` to number the revisions as in the source repo; and they take a minimal portion of the dump (and repo), anyway.